# Any active forum for Softbank NAO and Pepper?

Tags: forum, nao-robot, pepper

Softbank closed its forum for NAO and Pepper after it was abused by some misbehaved users and now I can’t find any active forum for NAO and Pepper. So want to ask if there is still any forum for NAO and Pepper exists somewhere you know of.

Answer (score 3):

The following google group is the only one I know:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran

Hope that helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Even though it is ROS oriented, thanks for the sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Other forums or usergroups besides stackoverflow are not known to me nor to the people from Softbank I talked to.

In June 2018 Softbank announced a new Developer Forum at

```
https://developer.softbankrobotics.com
```

Unfotunately it has never been accessible and i have no information when they plan to release it.

But it is still possible to access former posts from the old forum via direct link:
e.g.

```
https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/node/538
```

or I also like to use google to replace the not working search at the forum with a query like

```
"system time" site:https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/
```

to look for some former answers.

Comment: Sadly the direct links to the old forum no longer appear to work either

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same softbanks last week. And they told me that this is the developer forum is not in use anymore. They said that we should use stack exchange and try to search by the tag pepper and nao.

It looks like there are no forum at the moment.

Comment: The Softbank staff who replied you may not know the forum has been closed for months. I do hope that Softbank will open a new forum for Nao and Pepper as a new version of Nao has just been released few months ago.

Comment: I hope so too that they will open something its nowhere to discuss things except StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late and there is not much content there yet, but I've set up a new forum aimed at robotics developers in general but also with the hope to attract previous members of the NAO developer forum: https://robohack.org.uk/